# Tailwindcss – best way to dynamicly update the UI (no JS framework)

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css

What's the preferred strategy to dynamically update the using UI using tailwindcss (outside of JS frameworks)?

The "traditional" way is to use JS events and toggle some class, typically `is-active` or similar. It can be done in tailwind too, but it means to mix in the "traditional" or "semantic" CSS, probably somewhere else than in the markup itself, which does not seem to be "canonical".

**NOTE**: I do know how to toggle classes using JS, that's not the problem.

```
// I want to avoid this:
<button class="bg-blue-600 text-white">…

// somewhere else, let's say styles.css:
.is-active {
  @apply bg-blue-800
}
```

I am looking for a solution which resembles the v2 `darkMode` approach:

```
// From tailwindcss docs
<div class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800">
```

But I want to use my custom flags instead of `dark` – let's say `isActive`:

```
<button class="bg-blue-600 text-white isActive:bg-blue-800">
```

That would probably mean creating a custom variant, which is possible (according to docs), but it requires to use or create a plugin, which seems like overkill.

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: What is the issue with frameworks ? The build step, the weight or alike ? You could maybe use a super lightweight solution just to add a bit of reactivity: https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine There will pretty much be some JS if you want to update things dynamically, it will just be hidden under the hood.

Comment: There is no issue with frameworks, I use React with regularly (even with twin.macro). But at the moment I was just fiddling with html page + tailwind + parcel and I realize I don't know how to do the thing in html the way I would be satisfied with.

Comment: It's also that I don't know how you could achieve that kind of stuff without any JS or super ugly/hacky code. The `dark` can be used because of some static params, your `isActive` will be personal and dynamic.